# jQuery slider with ajax content loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I'm not JS expert so creating script from scratch will be difficult for me so I want to use plugin.
There is many slider plugins but all of them use pre-created elements and I want pagination with slide effect.

Do you know any plugin with that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) - especially the Tabs and Slider component. What you want sounds like you should combine two of the examples - [Slider Controlled Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#tabs) and [Content via ajax](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax).

Combining the two should be simple in terms of writing the JavaScript, although you might need to rewrite a large amount of CSS to create the desired pagination effect, and also look carefully at [jQuery UI Tab's ajax mode options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax).

Comment: Thanks for answer but what I was looking for is something like this http://slidesjs.com/ but with dynamic content loading feature, sorry for not clear description of problem :)

Comment: @Adam That's a little odd, since with sliders like those you probably would not want to use ajax - server-side includes would probably work better

Comment: Why it's odd? I just want ajax pagination with nice slide effect, I know that this is quite simple but with JS i prefer ready solutions. If such pagination plugin doesn't exists it's ok :)